# Как из php скрипта передать значение в python и получить результат в этот же php скрипт

Tags: php, python, массивы

Нам с товарищем в универе задали выполнить работу, а именно написать 
матричный калькулятор, я создал frontend https://webinclude.site/ (похвастаюсь),
а он занялся back-end, со мной всё понятно, но вот он работал на python, всё бы
ни чего, но я понятия не имею как все это связать, я хорошо знаю php. Мудрит мне
нужно из за того что нужно (тавтология) в бд сохранить историю привязанную к ip,
а это значить (в моём случае) что браузер должен обратиться к моему php скрипту,
он в свою очередь должен вызвать python скрипт передав ему два массива и код 
операции (целочисленное значение) а тот должен вернет результат в вызвавший его 
php скрипт, после чего данные отправятся в бд и пользователю

Я очень прошу вас показать на самых примитивных составленных вами примерах
как это сделать, а дальше я уже разберусь, только прошу вас хоть и примитивно но подробно. 
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Почему бы не писать всё на одном языке? То, что Вы хотите, даже звучит странно. Чем Вас и Вашего товарища не устраивает, допустим, `Python`?

Comment: Соглашусь с человеком выше) Пишите бэк н одном языке, к тому же вы хорошо знаете пхп, тогда вам не составит труда переписать скрипты

Comment: У нас один проект на двоих, и каждый из нас делал на том на чём умеет делать, я со свое стороны хорошо знаю html, css, js и php, а он на python и знает он его не на самом лучшем уровне, он даже не может реализовать связку с бд, да что там не знает как принять переменные с js, а мне эту проблему нужно решить, в пятницу сдавать проект и учить мне python совсем нет времени, а ему спасибо что хоть матрицы правильно считает его скрипт

Answer (score 0):

Оба эти языка умеют передавать и принимать POST запросы.